# CSS - Image not showing up as background image on all pages

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my background image to show on all of my html pages. I was able to get the image to be the full background on all pages before, but after I put the image into a folder in my project, it's no longer working. I have a folder called images inside of my project that contains the image I want to use as my background so I added the images/ path. I double checked the name of the folder, name of my image, and also to see if its a jpg (which it is). I also checked my CSS code and no not have body mentioned anywhere else or background-image anywhere else. Can't think of anything else I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
body{
background-image: url(images/main.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: `background-image: url(../images/main.jpg);`

Answer (score 2):

If the images directory is next to the css file then it will be like this

```
background-image: url(./images/main.jpg);
```

but if the style file is inside a directory next to the images directory, then it will be like this

```css
background-image: url(../images/main.jpg);
```